# In Continuum, how are the risky and high risk files calculated and included in "risk" metrics?

Tags: continuous-delivery, continuum

Continuum has the notion of being able to show Risk for a package manifest and as a high roll up metric for a version of a package that is in flight.

How are the risky files calculated, how are the high risk files calculated, and how are the risk dashboard metrics calculated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Product's description of the risk scores and calculations]

The continuum product now displays a helpful dialog that shows how the risk information is calculated and used.